# Ошибка UnicodeEncodeError django python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mod-wsgi

При загрузке файла на сервер возникает ошибка.

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /api/structure/ 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback:

File "/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = 
self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, 
*callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/env/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/structure/views.py" in post
  53.             config = openFile('/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/media/structure/upload/%s/config.conf' % (path_extr))

File "/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/structure/func.py" in openFile
  12.     return open(path, 'r').read()

File "/home/hl/www/hls/api/project/env/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py" in decode
  26.         return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
```

Подскажите в чём может быть проблема, использую связку apache2 + mod_wsgi + virtualenv.
Когда запускаю на севере django(python3 manage.py runserver) всё хорошо работает.

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке `return open(path, 'r').read()` файла func.py нужно [указать кодировку](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) файла config.conf

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогло.